# Error while calling php webservice from Windows Phone

Tags: windows-phone-8

I am having a local server using XAMPP. MY server is running and I am calling a PHP service that is residing in my system localhost from windows phone application using the code below.
But i am getting error that server not connected. PLease help me to fix it.

```
void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //callclient();
        System.Uri myUri = new System.Uri("http://myip/myfolder/check_login.php?/");
        HttpWebRequest myRequest = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(myUri);
        myRequest.Method = "POST";
        myRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        myRequest.BeginGetRequestStream(new AsyncCallback(GetRequestStreamCallback), myRequest);
    }

    void GetRequestStreamCallback(IAsyncResult callbackResult)
    {
        HttpWebRequest myRequest = (HttpWebRequest)callbackResult.AsyncState;
        // End the stream request operation
        Stream postStream = myRequest.EndGetRequestStream(callbackResult);

        // Create the post data
        string postData = "email_id=vipin@gmail.com&password=vipin123456";
        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);

        // Add the post data to the web request
        postStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
        postStream.Close();

        // Start the web request
        myRequest.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(GetResponsetStreamCallback), myRequest);
    }
    void GetResponsetStreamCallback(IAsyncResult callbackResult)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)callbackResult.AsyncState;

        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.EndGetResponse(callbackResult);
        using (StreamReader httpWebStreamReader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            string result = httpWebStreamReader.ReadToEnd();               
        }
    }
```

Comment: You should hook up to Fiddler to see if the connection is being made:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wsdevsol/archive/2013/06/05/configure-the-windows-phone-8-emulator-to-work-with-fiddler.aspx

Comment: @Matt : I will check that. But is there no simple way to connnect to php service?

Comment: It's no different than any other non ASMX/WCF web service.  I haven't inspected your code, but I think Fiddler would be the correct first step to understand what's wrong with the request.